# Creating an Annular snap-fit ratchet like object in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing, mathematics

Creating an Annular snap-fit ratchet like object in geometry nodes.

I'm having trouble selecting and moving the desired edges toward the center using **geometry nodes**.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

This is how I'm trying to get the teeth to look like.

[image: img3]

**My thoughts where to:**

1. Use modulo to select the edges.
2. Use the `Align Euler to Vector` node with a `Set Position` node to have all the ratchet edges point towards the center.

Please note: **This will be 3D printed to fit the dimensions of the object called annular outline**
The reason I'm creating this in geometry nodes is that it needs to be procedural. A lot of different sizes will be tested.

See attached Blend file below:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to modify this very often so you want to keep it procedural? If not I'm not sure why you want to create something with _Geometry Nodes_ which can be easily modeled, since you need to convert it all into real geometry for 3D printing anyway...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes it does need to be procedural.  A lot of different sizes will be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure from your post/file how you want your ratchet-surface to be melded with the existing ring. But it's maybe worth noting that a ratchet-profile is a *Curve Primitive > Star* with a twist of  `pi/number of teeth`...

[image]

Which, if some variation is used as a subgroup, may save a few nodes when constructing this component.

[image]

[image]